# The table in my page go past right my container. How to fix it?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is where I have the problem:

http://dmidland.byethost5.com/dmidlandProto2/AdminSide/reservationCustomers.php

I want to be inside the "container" of my page, and to be responsive as well. So if the user resizes the screen, or zooms in or out, It will not have an unpleasant view. Please help =)

Comment: SO does not like links to code. We need to see a [mcve] HERE - Please click the `<>` button and post enough HTML and CSS to show the issue

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Answer (score 0):

i do some search and fine this css for responsive table try it

td {
    display: block;

```
&:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
&:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}

&:before {
  content: attr(data-th)": "; // who knew you could do this? The internet, that's who.
  font-weight: bold;

  // optional stuff to make it look nicer
  width: 6.5em; // magic number :( adjust according to your own content
  display: inline-block;
  // end options

  @media (min-width: $breakpoint-alpha) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

}